# Add commas to output

Tags: r, output, addition

How can obtain my R output (let us say elements of a vector) separated by commas?
(i.e. not by space)

Currently I can only get output separated by space.

Comment: See `paste` collapse option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example:

```
#dummy vector
v <- c("a","1","c")

#separated with commas
paste(v,collapse=",")

#output
#[1] "a,1,c"
```

---

**EDIT 1:**
Thanks to @DavidArenburg:

```
cat(noquote(paste(v,collapse=",")))

a,1,c
```

**EDIT 2:**
Another option: by @RichardScriven

```
cat(v, sep = ",")
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Is there also a way to ommit   #[1]    and   "   before and after the results?   In other words can I just obtain them as:    a,1,c     ?

Comment: What are you trying to do after collapsing, output to a file, pass it to another function? `[1]` just shows the index for the first item, it is not part of output.

Comment: Try `cat(noquote(paste(v,collapse=",")))`

Comment: Same as `cat(v, sep = ",")`

Comment: @RichardScriven, nice one